# actionBar setCustomView not workin

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change dynamically the aspect of my actionbar. Applying the custom view layout i've created before, but still not working. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    }

        @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        Toast.makeText(this,item.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(item.toString() == "search"){         
        mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        mActionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Custom layout xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout 
              xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:orientation="horizontal" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <EditText android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the error? and can you share custom actionbar layout

Comment: just not showing. edited the post

Comment: check this post http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android

Comment: You're saying that the ActionBar is not rendering? I made a quick build of your code and can see it fine. You mentioned you want to 'change the aspect of your actionbar'. Are you perhaps saying that the `ActionBar` should have an editable text field, but does nothing when the ActionBar title is pressed?

Comment: exactly: the edit text dasnt appear

Answer (score 3):

consider trying `item.toString().equals("search")`

Comment: But i still  not understanding why the icon from the main activity (R.layout.activity_main) doesnt disappear

Comment: getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent); will hide the app icon. Please accept hirbodk's answer.